# Viewing an encrypted emacs org text file on android

Tags: password-protection

I use a gpg encrypted .org text file to store sensitive data, passwords etc. in a dropbox folder

I use this all the time on my various laptops

Having just purchased an android smartphone, I am wondering whether there is an efficient way for me to view that file on the phone?

I have installed dropbox app no prob and that works fine.

The unencrypting and viewing of the .org.gpg file however has not been so straightforward.

I have managed to decrypt the file on the phone with APG app, but it leaves a tmp unencrypted file in an obscure place which I'm not too thrilled about - and I can't see any way of sensibly viewing a .org file in android. I have seen/played with .org mode app but it doesn't really work very well.

Maybe I need to think laterally - could there be another way of sharing my sensitive data across laptop/phone that is secure, but also easy to use?

Comment: I don't know what you use to read/edit those files on Android, but concerning de- and encryption it might be worth trying [OpenKeychain](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.sufficientlysecure.keychain) (also [available on F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=org.sufficientlysecure.keychain)), which claims to interact fine with other apps. For alternatives, also be welcome to consult my app listing on [file encryption](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_encrypt#group_173).

Comment: well a .org file is just a text file at heart, so I guess a text editor that could work in conjunction with a decrypt app would suffice. I am thinking that I maybe hoping for too much for an app to be able to manipulate the .org file like emacs can?

Comment: May I suggest to ask at our sister site for specific app-combinations (see: [Where to ask for app recommendations?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/2060/16575)) SR is specialized on that part. Here at Android.SE we rather deal with "How to…" – which again doesn't fit over there :) The "How-to" part is basically the "Crypting app" invoking an app suitable for the content – which is what *OpenKeychain* does. [See here](https://www.openkeychain.org/apps/) for a list of apps reported to work with it. Basically, any app using the *OpenPGP API* or *OpenKeychain Intents* should cooperate.

Comment: I am actually making good progress with termux/emacs at the moment - all installed, need to hook up to dropbox and see if the built in emacs decrypt works. If so, my problem is solved. Thanks for the input Izzy

Comment: Glad to read! Be welcome to [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) then if solved :)

Comment: well I can decrypt .gpg files under termux now, i.e. I have apt-get'd gnupg ok - I can also view .org files in termux emacs no problem. But can I decrypt a .gpg file from within emacs? No I can't - I have taken the discussion on to https://plus.google.com/107409986037813400431/posts/jctjzQanAzS. If/when solved I'll post the answer..